# Redux save store as global variable on React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

```
import store from './store'

let reduxStore = ''
store.subscribe(() => {
  reduxStore = store.getState().username
  console.log(reduxStore) // I get USERNAME
})

console.log(reduxStore) // I get undefined
```

Is there a way to save `reduxStore` to global variable so I can use outside of `store.subscribe` function?

Thank you!

Comment: What's stopping you from using `let reduxStore = store.getState().username` ?

Comment: It does not get state outside of subscribe. I tried and it gave me undefined

Comment: Hmmm, that is weird, it works in my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ypnnkjk7/87/. (You need to scroll down to see the example)

Comment: By the way....... reduxStore  it is not a global variable but scope to the current module only.

Comment: any idea how to set `reduxStore` to be used in another function?

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the store you created to `window`:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, preloadedState);

// ...

window.reduxStore = store;
```

Then you can access the store from anywhere via for instance:
`window.reduxStore.getState().username`

However, I can't think of any valid reason for this to be necessary.